# AcquireTokenAsync timeouts Sometimes after some days #AzureActiveDirectory #ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, azure-active-directory

I have followed all related threads for deadlocking the AcquireTokenAsync operation in ASP.NET MVC. But still I am facing the timeout issue - sometimes after 1 day, sometimes after 3 days. When I restart my web app all works fine again.

Here is my Token Bearer Class which retrieves the token:

```
 public static class SSASTokenBearer
    {
        public static string Token = string.Empty;
        public static DateTime TokenExpiryTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        public static bool isTokenGenerated = false;
        public static int _counter = 0;
        public static bool IsThirdAttempt { get; set; }
        public static List<string> lstToken = new List<string>();
        public async static Task<string> GetAppOnlyAccessToken(string domain, string resourceUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret, string authUrl)
        {
            if (TokenExpiryTime > DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                //if (_counter.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Attempt.First)))
                //{
                //    isTokenGenerated = false;
                //}
                return Token;
            }
            else
            {
                await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
                //ClearTokenListAndAttemptCounter();
                try
                {
                    if (TokenExpiryTime < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        _counter++;
                        var authority = $"{authUrl}/{domain}/oauth2/token";
                        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
                        // Config for OAuth client credentials 
                        var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                        try
                        {
                            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientCred).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            //get access token
                            TokenExpiryTime = authenticationResult.ExpiresOn.DateTime;
                            Token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;   
                            //lstToken.Add(Token);
                            //isTokenGenerated = true;
                        }
                        catch (AdalException ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphoreSlim.Release();
                }
            }
            return Token;
        }
}
```

Here is the actual calling of the Bearer Token Class in the Open() method

```
 using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace BMIS2.Data.Repositories.PreventativeMaintenance.Dax
    {
        public enum Attempt
        {
            First = 1,
            Second = 2
        }

        public abstract class AbstactDal
        {
            public readonly string BMIS2DataBaseAzureSSAS = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMIS2DataBaseAzureSSAS"];

            private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            //change the connection password and url dynamically and use initial catalog from web.config
            private static string AzureSSASClientId;
            private static string AzureSSASClientSecret;
            private static string AzureSSASDomain;
            private static string AzureSSASURL = Helper.AzureSSASURL;
            private static string AzureAuthUrl;
            protected AdomdConnection DaxConnection = null;
            public AdomdCommand DaxCommand = null;
            private static readonly object padlock = new object();
            //private static Task<string> tskToken = null;
            private bool switchConnection = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SwitchConnection"]);
            private static string ConnectionStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMIS2DataBaseAzureSSASStatic"];
            //public async Task Execute(string query, Func<T> MethodName)

            public async Task ExecuteQuery(string query, Action MethodName)
            {
                if (switchConnection)
                {
                    await Open(ConnectionStr);
                }
                else
                {
                  await  Open($"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={AzureSSASURL};Initial Catalog={Helper.SSASDB};User ID=;Password={await Init()};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate");
                }
            await  ExecuteDaxReader(query, MethodName);
                Close();
            }

            private async Task<string> Init()
            {
                AzureSSASClientId = Helper.AzureSSASClientId;
                AzureSSASClientSecret = Helper.AzureSSASClientSecret;
                AzureSSASDomain = Helper.AzureSSASDomain;
                AzureAuthUrl = Helper.AzureAuthUrl;
                var token=   await SSASTokenBearer.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(AzureSSASDomain, $"https://{Helper.AzureSSASZone}", AzureSSASClientId, AzureSSASClientSecret, AzureAuthUrl);
                return token;

            }


            private async Task Open(string BMIS2DataBaseAzureSSAS)
            {

                DaxConnection = new AdomdConnection(BMIS2DataBaseAzureSSAS);
                try
                {
                    DaxConnection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                      Log.Warn(ex.Message.ToString());                
                      await Open($"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={AzureSSASURL};Initial Catalog={Helper.SSASDB};User ID=;Password={ await Init()};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate");


                }
                DaxCommand = new AdomdCommand();
                DaxCommand.Connection = DaxConnection;


            }

            private void Close()
            {
                DaxConnection.Close();
            }

            public abstract  Task ExecuteDaxReader(string query, Action MethodName);



        }


    }
```

In the implementation repository, each repository has its own common method to execute and read data from the data reader. We retrieve the DAX query from sql db and hit the same query to the SSAS Server.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using BMIS2.Common.CacheProviders;
using BMIS2.Data.Repositories.PreventativeMaintenance.Dax;
using BMIS2.Entity.ProcessPerformance;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

namespace BMIS2.Data.Repositories.PreventativeMaintenance.Imp
{
    public class DayOfTheWeekRepository : AbstactDal, IDayOfTheWeekRepository
    {
        public readonly string BMIS2DataBase = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public readonly int DefaultQuerySessionTime = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultQuerySessionTime"]);
        private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
        private List<AbstractProcessPerformanceDayOfTheWeek> lstRoCont = null;
        private  bool IsROCount=false;
        public DayOfTheWeekRepository(ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
        {
            _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        }

        public void GetIsRoCount()
        {

            try
            {

                using (var reader = DaxCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        IsROCount = ((reader["FACT_ROSale[RoCount]"] == null || reader["FACT_ROSale[RoCount]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["FACT_ROSale[RoCount]"])) > 0 ? true : false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               Log.Error(ex.Message.ToString());
               throw ex;
            }

        }


        public static bool HasValue( double value)
        {
            return !Double.IsNaN(value) && !Double.IsInfinity(value);
        }

        public void GetResultForRoCount()
        {

            try
            {

                lstRoCont = new List<AbstractProcessPerformanceDayOfTheWeek>();
                if (IsROCount)
                {
                    using (var reader = DaxCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            lstRoCont.Add(new ROCount()
                            {
                                DayOfTheWeek = (reader["[Day of Week]"] == null || reader["[Day of Week]"].ToString() == "") ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["[Day of Week]"]),
                                TestCount = (reader["[Test Count]"] == null || reader["[Test Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["[Test Count]"]),
                                RoCount = (reader["[RO Count]"] == null || reader["[RO Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["[RO Count]"]),
                                RoTestedPercent = Math.Round((reader["[RO Tested %]"] == null || reader["[RO Tested %]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["[RO Tested %]"]),1)
                                //RoTestedPercent =  HasValue(Math.Round((((reader["[Test Count]"] == null || reader["[Test Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["[Test Count]"])) / ((reader["[RO Count]"] == null || reader["[RO Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["[RO Count]"]))) * 100, 1)) ? Math.Round(((reader["[Test Count]"] == null || reader["[Test Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["[Test Count]"])) / ((reader["[RO Count]"] == null || reader["[RO Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["[RO Count]"])) * 100, 1) : 0,
                            });                           

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var reader = DaxCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {                            
                            lstRoCont.Add(new NoROCount()
                            {
                                DayOfTheWeek = (reader["[Day of Week]"] == null || reader["[Day of Week]"].ToString() == "") ? "" : Convert.ToString(reader["[Day of Week]"]),
                                //TotalCountPercent = HasValue(totalSum)? Math.Round((totalSum * 100),1) : 0,
                                TotalCountPercent = Math.Round((reader["[Test Count %]"] == null || reader["[Test Count %]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader["[Test Count %]"]), 1),
                                TestCount = (reader["[Test Count]"] == null || reader["[Test Count]"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["[Test Count]"])
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.Message.ToString());
                throw ex;
            }

        }



        public async Task<List<AbstractProcessPerformanceDayOfTheWeek>> GetDayOfTheWeekData(DayOfWeekFiltersObject filterSearch,bool IsRo)
        {
            IsROCount = IsRo;
            string RowCountQuery = string.Empty;
            // Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            //sw.Start();
            try { 
            using (var con = Database.GetConnection(BMIS2DataBase))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = IsRo? "[BMIS].[R_SP_GetRoCountQuery]" : "[BMIS].[R_SP_GetNoRoCountQuery]";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientid", filterSearch.ClientId));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartYear", DateTime.Parse(filterSearch.StartDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndYear", DateTime.Parse(filterSearch.EndDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocationId", filterSearch.SelectedLocationId));                                       
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(SetDbNull.SetDBNullIfEmpty("@ToolType", filterSearch.ToolTypeName));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(SetDbNull.SetDBNullIfEmpty("@TestType", filterSearch.TestType));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(SetDbNull.SetDBNullIfEmpty("@VehicleStatus", filterSearch.VehicleStatusName==null?null:String.Join(",", filterSearch.VehicleStatusName)));
                        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            RowCountQuery = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("query"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
            //sw.Stop();
           await this.ExecuteQuery(RowCountQuery, GetResultForRoCount);
            return lstRoCont;
        }






        public async Task<bool> IsRowCount(DayOfWeekFiltersObject filterObj)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Session["ClientIdRoCount"] = ClientId;
            string RowCountQuery = string.Empty;
            using (var con = Database.GetConnection(BMIS2DataBase))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "[BMIS].[R_SP_IsRoCountQuery]";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@clientid", filterObj.ClientId));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartYear", DateTime.Parse(filterObj.StartDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndYear", DateTime.Parse(filterObj.EndDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocationId", filterObj.SelectedLocationId));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(SetDbNull.SetDBNullIfEmpty("@ToolType", filterObj.ToolTypeName));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(SetDbNull.SetDBNullIfEmpty("@TestType", filterObj.TestType));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(SetDbNull.SetDBNullIfEmpty("@VehicleStatus", filterObj.VehicleStatusName==null?null:String.Join(",",filterObj.VehicleStatusName)));
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            RowCountQuery = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("query"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            await  this.ExecuteQuery(RowCountQuery, GetIsRoCount);
            return IsROCount;
        }


        public override async Task ExecuteDaxReader(string query, Action MethodName)
        {
            DaxCommand.CommandText = query;
            MethodName();

        }
    }
}
```

This is how there are 20 repositories that are implementing the same Abstract Dal.

I would be extremely thankful if anyone can help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through each Repository 1 by 1 and founded in few cases my colleagues has not put await to async functions which was causing deadlock. I have put this under monitoring and yes we have put ConfigureAwait(false).

I really appreciate your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try testing your code by setting your TokenCache to null in the AuthenticationContext constructor and removing the ConfigureAwait(false). Without ConfigureAwait(false) it should deadlock immediately and with ConfigureAwait(false) it should work every time. Have you ensured that you are hitting that section?

Apparently this is an issue with later versions. One workaround is to downgrade to version 2.19.208020213

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/1432